# Why doesn't pure fat taste better than pure sugar?

Tags: evolution, food, nutrition, perception, taste

I mean looking from evolutionary perspective sugar tastes sweet and individuals that had this perception ate more sugar and survived and those that didn't perceive sugar as sweet didn't eat it and died from hunger.

So the better (more caloric) food is - the better it should taste so that one would be more likely to eat it and if choice had to be made between berries or lard (assuming that food is scarce) one should go for lard as this would increase his chances of survival

Out of all foods [lard has the highest calorie content (898 cal per 100g) and therefore highest concentration of fat](https://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=lard%20calories&oq=lard%20ca&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l5.3847j0j7&safe=active) and yet it doesn't taste very nice.

There must be some explanation **why fat doesn't taste much better than sugar?**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59977/discussion-on-question-by-matas-vaitkevicius-why-doesnt-pure-fat-taste-better-t).